# MITM over wireless

Tags: wifi, man-in-the-middle, evil-twin

I was trying to perform MITM attack over wireless. The thing I used is

```
airbase-ng --essid "FAKEAP" -c 10 wlan0mon
```

to create a fake access point. This created a tap interface `at0` on which I ran `isc-dhcp-server` to hand out IP address.

When a client connects to this access point, it gets IP address and shows connected for like 10 seconds, after that I get disconnected and again connect to my AP for like 10 sec.

This connection and disconnection keeps on repeating. So can somebody tell what can be the possible solution?

**Steps I am doing are:**

```
$airmon-ng start wlan0

$vim /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.250;
option routers 192.168.1.1;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255
option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
}

$vim /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server
INTERFACESv4="at0"

$vim /etc/network/interfaces

ifauto at0
iface at0 inet static
address 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
broadcast 192.168.1.255

$airbase-ng --essid "FAKEAP" -c 10 wlan0mon
```

The above command starts the fake AP

```
$ifconfig at0 up

$iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

$iptables -A FORWARDING -i at0 -j ACCEPT

$systemctl restart isc-dhcp-server
```

Comment: Try without fixed channel. Maybe someone else also is using channel 10 and this might lead to connectivity problems.

Comment: Not working out tried that also anything else that could be wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you do not need to do:

```
airmon-ng start wlan0
```

In order to create an AP you do not need to have the WiFi interface in monitor mode.

You should also try to remove other processes using the WiFi interface:

```
airmon-ng check kill
```

The documentation says:

> “check” will show any processes that might
>   interfere with the aircrack-ng suite. It is strongly recommended that
>   these processes be eliminated prior to using the aircrack-ng suite.
>   “check kill”

Some of these processes could interfere with aircrack.

And in my opinion you should check 
[mana toolkit](https://github.com/sensepost/mana), is a suitte of scripts focused on mitm attacks over wireless.

For example this [script](https://github.com/sensepost/mana/blob/master/run-mana/start-nat-simple.sh) from mana toolkit will create a rogue AP. You will only need to set the network interfaces.